# AI Thinker A9G TCP\IP Data Transmission Problem

Tags: tcp, embedded, ascii

**Hello, community**

I have a problem with `AT+CIPSEND` Command.
It receives the input data as ASCII data, so when I check the server I receive the data in the wrong format.
I expect to receive the data in bytes.
So I have converted the byte array to an ASCII array to receive it correctly.
But in ASCII there is a unique characters like `1` and `8` the serial communication performs the action of these special characters rather than sending them.

Bytes array to send `char bytes[] = { 120, 120, 13, 1, 8, 103, 149, 144, 52, 66, 103, 130, 0, 13, 51, 81, 13, 10 };`

I receive `{ 120, 120, 13, 103, 149, 144, 52, 66, 103, 130, 0, 13, 51, 81, 13, 10 };`

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution use `AT+CIPSEND=n` where `n` is a number of bytes to send.

Example `char bytes[] = { 120,120,13,1,8,103,149,144,52,66,103,130,0,13,51,81,13,10 };`

execute `AT+CIPSEND=18`

then send the 18 bytes value.

```
    char bytes[] = { 120,120,13,1,8,103,149,144,52,66,103,130,0,13,51,81,13,10 };
    A9G.print("AT+CIPSEND=18\r\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 18; ++i) { A9G.write(bytes[i]); }
```